# Load data into Greenplum DB using MapReduce or Sqoop

Tags: sqoop, greenplum

I want to try loading the data into Greenplum using mapreduce or sqoop. For now, the ways to load greenplum db from hdfs is, creating an extenrnal table with gphdfs and then loading internal table. I want to tryout solution to directly load the data into greenplum with sqoop or mapreduce. I need some inputs on how i can proceed on this. Could you please help me out.?

Answer (score 0):

With regards to Sqoop, **Sqoop export** will help to achieve this.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqoop/sqoop_export.htm

Comment: This is just sqoop export to regular RDBMS databases. I need to know, whether any one tried pushing data into GreenPlum.

Answer (score 0):

While not sqoop, I am currently in the experimental phases of using Greenplum's external tables to load from hdfs.  So far it seems to perform.